# Webcam showing blank grey image

Tags: webcam, thinkpad, camera

I'm having a frustrating problem with my computer. I have a lenovo thinkpad t510, and my webcam is just returning a blank grey image for some reason. I've checked device manager, it is there as a camera, and I have also checked and know that I have all the latest driver updates for the camera. It was working before. However, I haven't used it in a while, last time I used it was 2 months ago. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Also, when I try to use it, the physical camera indicator light goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a general system update and that fixed it. Thanks for the help though!